# How can I transfer ERC20 token by another smart contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, erc20

I have designed an erc20 token and a smart contract to transfer that token, but when I trigger the function to transfer, the remix told me the following graph.

[image]

What I did was to deploy the token smart contract and then the DAO smart contract, then call the creatSubDAO function to start the transfer.

The relative code is below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: GPL-3.0
 pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;


interface IERC20 {

function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);

function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);


event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}
```

contract Dtoken:

```
contract Dtoken is IERC20{

string public name = "DAO Token";
string public symbol = "D";
uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000000000000000000000;
uint8 public decimals = 18;

mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

constructor() {
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
}

function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= balanceOf[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
   }
 }
```

contract MasterDao:

```
import "./Dtoken.sol";

contract MasterDAO {

uint proposalNum;

mapping (address => Member) public members;
mapping (uint => Proposal) public proposals;
mapping (uint => SubDAO) public subDAOs;
// SubDAO[] public subDAOs;

function createSubDAO (uint _poolGap, uint _DAOID, uint _rate, Dtoken _token) public returns (address daoAddress) {
    SubDAO subDAO = new SubDAO(_poolGap, _DAOID, msg.sender, _rate, this, _token);
    daoAddress = address(subDAO);
}}
```

SubDao Contract:

```
 contract SubDAO {

uint proposalNum;
address lender;
uint poolGap;
uint currentStake;
uint256 public DAOID;
MasterDAO master;
address stakeItem;
uint rate;
Dtoken public token;

mapping(address => Member) members;
mapping (uint => Proposal) public proposals;

string[] description;

event Transfrom(address, uint);

struct Member {
    address memberAddress;
    string nickName;
    bool alreadyExist;
}


struct Proposal {
    string description;
    address payable recipient;
    bool executed;
    uint proposalID;
    address[] agreeMembers;
    address[] disagreeMembers;
    bool exectuable;
    uint amount;
    Dtoken token;
}

modifier membership (MasterDAO masterDAO, address _staker){
    require(masterDAO.addressExist(_staker) == true);
    _;
}

modifier lenderLimit {
    require(msg.sender == lender);
    _;
}

modifier balanceLimit(uint amount) {
    require(amount <= poolGap - currentStake);
    _;
}

constructor (uint _poolGap, uint _DAOID, address _lender, uint _rate, MasterDAO caller, Dtoken _token) {
    currentStake = 0;
    poolGap = _poolGap;
    DAOID = _DAOID;
    lender = _lender;
    master = caller;
    rate = _rate;
    token = _token;
    token.transferFrom(address(this), address(this), 10);
}
```

Did I do anything wrong to transfer the token? Thanks!

Comment: Is createSubDAO function into the DToken contract?

Comment: Could you send the entire code?

Comment: I have put the entire code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the SubDao constructor:

```
token.transferFrom(address(this), address(this), 10);
```

This snippet is trying to transfer tokens from the just created SubDao address (1st argument) to the very same address (2nd argument).

The newly created SubDao address most likely doesn't own any tokens to transfer **from** in the first place.

---

If you want to transfer tokens from the `MasterDao` to the newly created `SubDao`, you can remove the `transferFrom()` from the `SubDao` constructor, and implement the transfer in the `MasterDao` function `createSubDAO()`:

```
function createSubDAO (uint _poolGap, uint _DAOID, uint _rate, Dtoken _token) public returns (address daoAddress) {
    SubDAO subDAO = new SubDAO(_poolGap, _DAOID, msg.sender, _rate, this, _token);
    daoAddress = address(subDAO);

    // transfer 10 units of the `Dtoken`
    // from the `MasterDao` address
    // to the newly created `SubDao` address
    // assuming that `MasterDao` has sufficient token balance
    Dtoken(_token).transfer(daoAddress, 10);
}}
```

Comment: That's a clear remedy for that but there is another problem: how can I transfer the DToken from DToken contract to the MasterDAO contract, I have tried to use token.transfer(address(masterDAOaddress), 10000) in the constructor of the MasterDAO but the same error message occured.

Comment: The constructor of MasterDAO is as below :
`
    constructor(address tokenAddress) {
        Dtoken token = Dtoken(tokenAddress);
        token.transfer(address(this), 100000);
    }`

what I did was deploy the DToken at first, then copy the address of DToken to the parameter of the constructor of MasterDAO

Comment: @AlanK The snippet in your MasterDAO constructor from the comment again tries to transfer tokens **from** the MasterDAO (as the `transfer()` function is invoked by the MasterDAO address in the constructor) **to** to very same MasterDAO address (the first param)... If you want to transfer tokens **from** the DToken, you need to invoke the `transfer()` function **in** the DToken contract (so that the DToken is the sender), passing it the MasterDAO address as the first param (the receiver)... TLDR: The `transfer()` function (when called from a contract) sends the tokens from the caller contract.

Comment: Thank you very much! So is it correct that if I call a `transfer()` or `transferFrom()`  funciton, the caller of the function is the smart contract but not the deployer of the smart contract? For example, I used address A to deploy a smart contract on address B, and the transfer() function transfers token from B but not A.

Comment: @AlanK Exactly.